# Opening webpage returned by HTTP POST from R

Tags: r

I'm attempting to integrate a web-based gene ontology (GO) analysis tool into my R based analysis.  Following instructions here: http://revigo.irb.hr/invokeRevigoAndFillFields.html I have made HTTP POST requests using both the rCurl and httr packages.  Unfortunately, I can't figure out what to do with the output.

The POST request should result in a prefilled version of http://revigo.irb.hr that is ready to be submitted for analysis. This appears to work fine with the html form POST method.

This is my first exposure to POST so I may be missing something very obvious.

Ultimately, this will be part of Shiny application that generates lists of GO ids for input into revigo.

```
goList = "GO:0009268 1e-14
GO:0010447 1e-14
GO:0000027 1e-297
GO:0042255 1e-297
GO:0042257 1e-297
GO:0042273 1e-297"

library(httr)
r_httr = POST("http://revigo.irb.hr/", body = list(inputGoList = goList))

library(RCurl)
r_rcurl = postForm("http://revigo.irb.hr/", inputGoList = goList)
```

Comment: `httr::content(r_httr)`

Comment: httr::content(r_httr) returns html corresponding to the submission page for revigo, not content with any information I want.  Is there a way to go from POST request in R to open webpage where analysis can continue?